# How to create multidimensional multitype c++ vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm looking for a way to create a C++ vector which will hold class object ( which is multi dimensional array - 3D coordinate system location mapper ) and int object which describes it in some way.

I have found many examples of multidimensional single type vectors like

```
vector <vector<int>> vec (4, vector<int>(4));
```

I need a dynamic structure which can grow/shrink in the heap as time progress with  flexibility of the vector type.

Comment: Well, it *is* a [std::vector<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). So what kind of growth (or shrinking) do you think it *can't* do? (and +1 for NOT using `new` in this given-trivial snippet).

Comment: Either use a `boost::variant`, an `std::pair`, or a user-defined struct of some sort. Could you make the question more specific with a code example or anything else so you can tell us _exactly_ what you're aiming to achieve?

Comment: If all your objects are derived from a common base class you could use `std::vector<std::pair<int,std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>>>`.

Comment: Every node in 3D array is a class ( 'class x' array[x][y][z] ). In that class there should be a vector which describes 3D position of an object ( class ) and it's relationship with other nodes. The class should have the ability to connect with other nodes describing its connection strength with an integer and adding neighbouring node coordinates. So the vector should have two values: 'special type' which describes the position in 3D matrix and Integer with 'strength'. It should be dynamic and grow/shrink over time depending on the number of established connectionsAnyalternative is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Your position object, whatever the declaration may be
struct Position { int x, y, z; };

struct Connection {
    Position position;
    int strength;
};

// This is what you want your node class to be
// based on the comment you gave.
struct Node {
    Position position;
    std::vector<Connection> connections;
};

// A vector is dynamic and resizable.
// Use std::vector::push_back and std::vector::emplace_back methods 
// insert elements at the end, and use the resize method to modify 
// the current size and capacity of the vector.
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Node>>> matrix;
```

An alternative would be to define a `Connection` as an `std::pair<Position, int>`, but that wouldn't be very good because if you wanted to add more information to the Connection in the future, you'd have to change more code than you should.

If you want to resize the whole  multidimensional array, you'll have to iterate over all the vectors one by one with a loop and call the `resize` method.

Comment: looks like an elegant solution but I would still like to avoid 'struct' and use class.. I'll give it a try... TnX.. If anyone else have any other ( or better ) implementation I would really like to hear about it...

Comment: template <typename T1=int,typename T2=int,typename T3=int,typename T4=int> Class Node { private T1 X; T2 Y; T3 Z; T4 Strength; //etc etc and then make a vector ?

Comment: There is no difference between structs and classes other than the fact that members in structs are public by default and members in classes are private by default. Also, yes, that should work fine.

Comment: yeah... but why would you suggest (C ) struct over class or template ? is there a particular reason ? maybe speed ?

Comment: Not at all. There is no speed difference here. The only reason I typed `struct` instead of `class` is because these are PODs and I didn't want to type `public:` after their first lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get "type flexibility" out of a `std::vector` is to have it store a polymorphic type. Based on your example, it looks like you may want a `std::vector` of `struct`s:

```
struct s
{
    int i;
    double d;
    char c;
    bool b;
};

std::vector<s> vec;

// elements can be accessed as such:
auto i = vec[0].i;
auto d = vec[0].d;
auto c = vec[0].c;
auto b = vec[0].b;
```

Comment: how about [code] vector <vector<class>> vec (2, vector<int>(4));

Comment: No, a `vector` holds a single type of element. You're attempting to declare a `vector` of `vector` of `class`, and trying to initialize it with two elements of type `vector` of `int`. Looking at your comment on the question you'll need something more than a `vector` of structs. I'll come back to this once I get the kid to bed. If it's still open.